# Code displays index out of bound error in VSCode, but gets output in Colab

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the below python code i'm getting the output Candy Crush Saga in colab. But in the VSCode i'm getting index out of bound exception.

```
from urllib import request
from lxml import html
import requests

class AppCrawler:
    def __init__(self,starting_url,depth):
        self.starting_url=starting_url
        self.depth=depth
        self.apps=[]

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_app_from_link(self.starting_url)
        return 

    def get_app_from_link(self,link):
        startpage=requests.get(link)
        tree=html.fromstring(startpage.text)
        name= tree.xpath('//h1[@class="product-header__title app-header__title"]/text()')[0]
        print(name)


class App:
    def __init__(self,name,developer,price,links):
        self.name=name
        self.developer=developer
        self.price=price
        self.links=links

    def __str__(self):
        return("Name: "+ self.name.encode('UTF-8')+ "\n\r Developer: "+ self.developer.encode('UTF-8')+
        "\n\r Price: "+ self.price .encode('UTF-8'))

crawler=AppCrawler("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731",0)
crawler.crawl()
```

It gives index out of bound exception in VSCode

Comment: on which line is there an index out of bounds exception? it doesn't look like you're indexing anything, are you sure this is the code VSCode is running?

Comment: there is amazing tool called a debugger, you should try it, it is not human and is on your computer

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rosh/Desktop/Test/datacr.py", line 36, in <module>
    crawler.crawl()
  File "/Users/rosh/Desktop/Test/datacr.py", line 12, in crawl
    self.get_app_from_link(self.starting_url)
  File "/Users/rosh/Desktop/Test/datacr.py", line 18, in get_app_from_link
    name= tree.xpath('//h1[@class="product-header__title app-header__title"]/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

This is the o/p from VSCode

Comment: edit your question with this text, hard to read the error message in a comment

Comment: what is the result of the `tree.xpath(...)` call, remove the `[0]` part, most likely it is not found what you ask for

Comment: when I remove the [0], its giving me an empty list. The issue is that it works perfect in google colab, but the same code gives me error in VSCode

Comment: then analyze `startpage.text` if the xpath query can be found

Comment: always build tests in the code in case it can't be found, if they change the page layout you should gracefully make note of that